# Button Borders Issue

Tags: html, css, button, html-table

I'm new into frontend and I have been trying to design a calculator. I used table because I think it is the best option. I used `<button>` element in order to make it clickable, but when I use the attribute ( border: none or 0) it's not clickable anymore , so what's causing that?

Also I would like to know how to change the button background ( I have tried to inherit it and that works but I don't think this is practical).

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  /* padding: 0; */
  /* margin: 0 auto; */
  font-size: 2rem;
  /* text-align: center; */
  background-color: #d8d9db;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0%;
  background-color: black;
}

.screen {
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  text-align: right;
}

tr {
  border: 8px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}

td {
  /* border: 5px solid red; */
  background-color: #d8d9db;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0.5rem;
}

button {
  font-size: 3rem;
  color: black;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.col4 {
  background-color: #df974c;
  color: white;
  width: 25%;
}

.col4 button {
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.butc {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #d8d9db;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.but0 {
  width: 75%;
  background-color: #d8d9db;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <section class="screen">0</section>
  <section class="calc-buttons">
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2" class="butc"><button>C</button></td>
          <td class="numbs"><button>&larr;</button></td>
          <td class="col4"><button>&divide;</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="numbs"><button>7</button></td>
          <td class="numbs"><button>8</button></td>
          <td class="numbs"><button>9</button></td>
          <td class="col4"><button>&times;</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="numbs"><button>4</button></td>
          <td class="numbs"><button>5</button></td>
          <td class="numbs"><button>6</button></td>
          <td class="col4"><button>&minus;</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="numbs"><button>1</button></td>
          <td class="numbs"><button>2</button></td>
          <td class="numbs"><button>3</button></td>
          <td class="col4"><button>&plus;</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3" class="but0"><button>0</button></td>
          <td class="col4"><button>&equals;</button></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: The button is still clickable, you just removed the visual indication about the click when you removed the border

Comment: so how can keep the visual indication while removing the border? and do you think designing the calculator using divs is more functional?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Button default active state depends on `border` when setting border to none for the button this means that `border-style` set in `:active` won't work.

So in order to remove the border but reserve the clickable effect you need to add something like this in css

```
button:active{
    border: 1px inset black
}
```

and consider specifying different buttons widths and heights to match the calculator style which will help in their background colors